# Clicar e passa url para php usando ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Como eu faço para pegar o link ao clicar ?

exemplo: eu tenho um iframe com um link que direciona para uma pagina, eu quero pegar esse link, e passar via ajax pro php.

Comment: Podes colocar o código HTML que tens? Esse iframe está no mesmo dominio?

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
                          integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
                          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                 <iframe id="xframe" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe> 
                 <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() 
                        {
                            var aqui = $("#xframe").attr("src");//Pegando o link do Iframe
                            /*RELALIZANDO O AJAX COM O METODO POST*/

                            $.post("/meulink.com.br", {"endereco": aqui}, function(data)
                            {
                                alert(data);

                            });

                        });


                 </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Seria muito bom você postar aqui o html para ter-mos uma noção do que esta querendo, mas este exemplo creio que ira ajuda-lo.